# How to add components conditionally inside another component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm testing out Knockout's components features and so far have been able to use it in several scenarios successfully. Now I've come to a scenario which I can't find a resource on how to do. I want to add a component inside another component based on some keyword. Here is some snippet:

**Template for parent component**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**View model for parent component**

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "ko-postbox", "text!./parent.html"], function($, ko, kopost, template) {

    function displayChildContent(value) {
        switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
            case "child":
                //
                // How to load child component?
                //
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    function ParentViewModel() {
        ko.postbox.subscribe("child-click", function(newValue) {
            displayChildContent(newValue);
        }, this);
    }

    return { viewModel: ParentViewModel, template: template };
});
```

**Template for child component**

```
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

**View model for child component**

```
define(["text!./child.html"], function(template) {

    function ChildViewModel() {
    }

    return { viewModel: ChildViewModel, template: template };
});
```

The click is triggered but I don't know how to add the child template inside the parent template. Also, I plan to have some data passed from parent to child using params binding of custom element. After I add the child template to the parent, will it still be able to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent component add a line similar to:

```
<!-- ko if: childTmpl --><!-- ko component: {name: 'child'} --><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
```

where `childTmpl` is a boolean observable subscribed to `child-click`.
Now, this might present a little problem if you don't want to tightly couple the component named 'child' inside the parent. In that case, you could still replace it with a(n observable) property in the parent viewModel, or even alternate dynamically. It would become:

```
<!-- ko if: childTmpl --><!-- ko component: {name: childComp} --><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->
```

where `childComp` is a property on `ParentViewModel` which you can fill through params/ fixed value/ observable. Here are the sample models I tested with:

```
function ParentViewModel(params) {
  this.childComp = params && params.child || 'child';
  this.childTmpl = ko.observable(true).subscribeTo("child-click");
}

function ChildViewModel(params) {
  this.buttonClicked = ko.observable(true).publishOn("child-click");
}
ChildViewModel.prototype.toggle = function() { 
  this.buttonClicked(!this.buttonClicked()); 
};
```

In the test case, clicking a button in the child component (which is originally shown) triggers `buttonClicked` to `false`, which then updates `childTmpl` to `false` as well, removing the child component. See the full fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ohdodfzr/2/

As for your second question:

> Also, I plan to have some data passed from parent to child using params binding of custom element.

Yes, you can still do this. You could even pass the entire parent viewModel through the component binding in the parent's template, eg:

```
<!-- ko component: {name: 'child', params: {parent: $data}} -->
```

Comment: Thanks. I still haven't got it to work due to a different problem but I think your solution is correct. I am now facing a new problem. Maybe you can have a look (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899738/cant-bind-observable-inside-component-to-an-if-binding)? I'll still mark this as the answer as I think this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @g_b I see a couple of issues with your code in the second question. The first error `[Object Object] ` is because you're passing an **instance** instead of a constructor. If your component only has 1 instance, you can return `viewModel: {instance: model}`, else you have to set the postbox subscribe inside the constructor (like I did here). Not sure if the postbox subscribe fires directly, but you should set it **after** model is declared anyhow. Also done stuff with requirejs & postbox & I had to set `if (!ko.postbox) ko.postbox = kopost;` for it to work, but dunno if that matters here.