# Can't bind observable inside component to an If-binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am trying to load a component conditionally using an if-binding. However, I can't change the value of the observable that is assigned to the if-binding using the construct below since, I think, the functions that should change the observable are outside the view model. I initially did this because this is what's done in the sample in KnockoutJS's site:

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "ko-postbox", 
    "text!./parent.html"], function($, ko, kopost, template) {

    ko.postbox.subscribe("child-click", function(newValue) {
        ParentViewModel.prototype.displayChildContent(newValue);
    }, this);

    function ParentViewModel() {
        //
        // I NEED TO CHANGE THIS FROM OUTSIDE THE VIEW MODEL
        //
        this.childClicked = ko.observable(false); 
    }

    ParentViewModel.prototype.displayParentContent = function(value) { 
        switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    ParentViewModel.prototype.displayChildContent = function(value) { 
        switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
            case "child1":
                alert();
                //
                // I NEED TO CHANGE OBSERVABLE HERE
                //
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    return { viewModel: ParentViewModel, template: template };
});
```

Then I tried doing it this way: I put the functions inside the view model and then assign the view model in a variable. Notice the return value: I used "instance" instead of the usual "viewModel" because when I use "viewModel", an error appears "Uncaught Error: Component 'parent': Unknown viewModel value: [object Object]" and also, it is constructed twice.

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "ko-postbox", 
    "text!./parent.html"], function($, ko, kopost, template) {

    ko.postbox.subscribe("child click", function(newValue) {
        model.displayChildContent(newValue);
    }, this);

    function ParentViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.childClicked = ko.observable(false);

        self.displayChildContent = function(value) { 
            switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
                case "child1":
                    alert();
                    self.childClicked(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
    }

    var model = new ParentViewModel();

    return { instance: model, template: template };
});
```

When I do this, the if-binding does not work. The error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return childClicked }"
Message: childClicked is not defined"

Here is the parent HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <!-- ko if: childClicked -->
    <!-- ko component: {name: "parent"} --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to control the rendering of a component from inside it as well as outside it. The trick is to [use params](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#api) to pass the controlling observable to the component.

In this example, the checkbox in the parent controls the rendering of the component, but the component also has a Hide Me button that triggers the un-rendering via the same controlling observable.

As the snippet runner seems to be down right now, here's the same thing as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tje9e2yy/

```js
function ChildViewModel(params) {
  this.hideMe = function() {
    params.show(false);
  };
}

ko.components.register('child-component', {
  viewModel: ChildViewModel,
  template: {
    element: 'child-template'
  }
});

var vm = {
  childClicked: ko.observable(false)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<template id="child-template">
  <button data-bind="click:hideMe">Hide Me</button>
</template>
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:childClicked" />
  <!-- ko if: childClicked -->
  <!-- ko component: {name: "child-component", params:{show:childClicked}} -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```